# Error al intentar guardar un registro en una tabla con valor nulo en un campo relacionado con otra tabla usando Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

He creado una clase de entidad desde la base de datos con clave externa, el conjunto de atributos de esta manera:

```
@Entidad
@Table (name = "PERSONA")

// ....

@JoinColumn (name = "ID_DEPARTMENTO", referencedColumnName = "ID_DEPARTMENTO")
@ManyToOne
Departamento privado idDepartamento;
```

En la otra clase de entidad, la configuración se establece así

```
@Entidad
@Table (nombre = "DEPARTAMENTO")

// ...

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "idDepartmento")
Colección privada <Persona> personaCollection;
```

El valor de idDepartmento en la tabla Persona puede ser nulo, porque al principio no se tiene esa información

Cuando intento guardar sin este valor, aparece el siguiente error:

org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: el objeto hace referencia a una instancia transitoria no guardada.

pero no necesito guardar nada en el departamento.

Según he leído se resuelve poniéndole la modalidad Cascade.ALL, pero esto guarda un registro en blanco en la tabla departamento (esto no es lo que quiero).

¿Cómo puedo guardar el registro en la tabla persona cuando el valor de idDepartmento es nulo?

Comment: probaste con @ManyToOne(optional=true) ?

Comment: @Alex por defecto *optional* es *true* (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#optional--)